# Reload image without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have little experience with javascript, I'm trying to make the image update but I'm not succeeding. This image comes through an API

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A98jD.jpg)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload = function(){

      setInterval("atualizarqr()",3000); // troca imagem a cada 3 segundos      

   }

   function atualizarqr(){

      var img = document.getElementById('img').src;     

     
         document.getElementById('img').src = "https://santoaleixo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Logo-Santo-Aleixo-3.png";
   }

</script>

<body onload="atualizarqr">
            <img src="" id="img"/>
        </body>
```

Comment: Please don't make duplicate postings. Instead add all the details to your question and un-accept the answer while you're still learning on how to use SO. There is nothing inherently wrong getting started and doing some mistakes.